# CSV file to JS object for nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm looking to retrieve data from a local CSV file, store it in an Object, then send it via an API. But when I try to display `data[i].id;` to see if I can get a value, it is `undefined`.

I use [ya-csv](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ya-csv) to parse the CSV file.

**myFile.csv**

```
id;name;email;
1;John;john@doe.com
2;Jane;jane@doe.com
```

**csvParser.js**

```
const csv = require('ya-csv');

const data = [];
const file = 'myFile.csv';

function loopForPrint() {
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    let id = data[i].id;
    console.log(id);
  }
}

function csvToJson() {
  var reader = csv.createCsvFileReader(file, {columnsFromHeader: true, 'separator': ';'});
  reader.addListener('data', function(data) {
    data.push(data);
    loopForPrint();
  })
  reader.addListener('end', function() {
    console.log('end');
  });
};
```

Comment: I've had good luck with [csv-parser](https://www.npmjs.com/package/csv-parser)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you can remove the tailing `;` so that there won't be an empty key and undefined value

Secondly, you can replace this code with

```
reader.addListener('data', function(data) {
  data.push(data);
  loopForPrint();
})
```

this one

```
reader.addListener('row', function(row) {
  data.push(row);
  loopForPrint();
})
```

as data is defined globally and locally will create a conflict

**Here is the complete code**

```
const csv = require('ya-csv');

const data = [];
const file = 'myFile.csv';

function loopForPrint() {
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    console.log(data[i].id);
  }
}

function csvToJson() {
  var reader = csv.createCsvFileReader(file, {columnsFromHeader: true, 'separator': ';'});
  reader.addListener('data', function(row) {
    data.push(row);
  })
  reader.addListener('end', function() {
    loopForPrint();
    console.log('end');
  });
};

csvToJson()
```

**Output**

```
1
2
end
```

I have also created [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/node-n6xu4g?file=index.js) for this if you want to look at it